# How to make my RSS Feed use more than one image for each news?

Tags: html, javascript, css, rss

Sorry for my really bad english (I also dont know how to build the title very well but I hope it's good enough to understand what I'm trying to do).

I bought this website template, the guy I bought it from has corona and is unavailable right now, that's why I'm asking for help here ^^

1. This is my homepage https://www.ragnarokeurope.net/
2. When you open this page, you see my News RSS feed and 4 pictures.
3. **What I'm trying to do is: use a different picture for each of the news.**
4. If you don't want to click the link, here is a picture of what Im talking about
   [image]

The code for the pictures, I have it here. As you can see, it's made so everything uses the same picture. It would be awesome if somebody could help me change it.

```
<div id="RO_ACTU_IMG">

    <?php
    $newslimit = (int)Flux::config('CMSNewsLimit');
    require_once('autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url(Flux::config('CMSNewsRSS'));
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
    $feed->init();
    $feed->handle_content_type();
    ?>

    <?php foreach($feed->get_items(0,4) as $rssItem): ?>

    <?php
    // These News Images are stored in /themes/<theme_name>/img/news/
    // In the if-statement, use the name of your News item to dsiplay $newsimage in the feed.
    if($rssItem->get_title() == "The League Of Levelers"){$newsimage = "league";}
    elseif($rssItem->get_title() == "Halloween Has Landed"){$newsimage = "halloween";}
    else{$newsimage = "generic";}
    ?>

    <div class="RO_ACTU_IMG_news">
        <a href="<?php echo $rssItem->get_link(0) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->themePath('img/news/'.$newsimage.'.jpg') ?>" alt="NEWS"></a>
        <div class="RO_NEWS">
            <h3 class="RO_NEWS_titre"><a href="<?php echo $rssItem->get_link(0) ?>"><?php echo $rssItem->get_title() ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo date(Flux::config('DateFormat'),strtotime($rssItem->get_date()))?></p>
            <p><?php echo substr($rssItem->get_description(),0,170) ?>...</p>
            <div class="RO_readmore"><p><a href="<?php echo $rssItem->get_link(0) ?>">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it is possible that get_Title() is not eval'ing to your text. None of the titles in the image match the text you are comparing as well.